# Right way to use vmaf with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, videoquality

I am trying to calculate the **VMAF** score of a processed video wrt the original file.

**Command I have used:**

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -stats -i original.mp4 -i processed.mp4 -lavfi "[0]null[refdeint];[refdeint]scale=1920:1080:flags=neighbor[ref];[1]setpts=PTS+0.0/TB[b];[b]scale=1920:1080:flags=neighbor[c];[c][ref]libvmaf=log_fmt=json:phone_model=1:model_path={model_path_here}/vmaf_v0.6.1.json:n_subsample=1:log_path=log.json" -f null -
```

Now as per the official documentation of `vmaf with ffmpeg` found [here](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/resource/doc/ffmpeg.md), it says `source/reference` file followed by the `encoded/distorted/processed` file.

But almost all of the blogs I came across, they are using the other way round order of the args, i.e. `processed` file followed by the `original` file.

Few examples:

1. https://medium.com/@eyevinntechnology/keep-an-eye-on-the-video-quality-b9bcb58dd5a1: search for "Using VMAF within FFMPEG" in it.
2. https://websites.fraunhofer.de/video-dev/calculating-vmaf-and-psnr-with-ffmpeg/: search for "Metric Calculation with FFmpeg" in it.

**EDIT**

**NOTE:** Changing the order does change the VMAF score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not really mater how you are **specifying source files** in command line.
It is important how **video streams supplied to libvmaf filter**.

By default, source specified first in command line will become stream with index=0, source specified second -- stream with index=1.

You can specify the how these streams are supplied to libvmaf filter, but you do not have to. If you have not done this, the streams with index 0 and 1 will be supplied to the filter in that order.

Lets look at your examples.

Netflix manual (I removed not needed parts):

```
ffmpeg ... -i src01_hrc00_576x324.yuv \
       ... -i src01_hrc01_576x324.yuv \
    -lavfi "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[reference]; \
            [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[distorted]; \
            [distorted][reference]libvmaf=model_path={your_vmaf_dir}/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.json" \
    -f null -
```

Notice that video stream with index=0 (the one that was specified first in command line) is renamed to **reference** (`[0:v]...[reference]`) and the video stream with index=1 (the one that is the second in command line) renamed as **distorted** (`[1:v]...[distorted]`).

But when they are sending to libvmaf in the order is: distorted then reference (`[distorted][reference]libvmaf`).

Article on medium:

```
ffmpeg -i distorted-file -i reference-file -lavfi libvmaf -f null –
```

FFMpeg manual:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mpg -i ref.mpg -lavfi libvmaf -f null -
```

Distorted file have index=0
Reference file have index=1.
As there is no any renaming/remapping, they will be sent to libvmaf in original order: 0 then 1 (distorder then reference). It is equal to `[0][1]libvmaf`. So video streams order supplied to libvmaf is exactly the same as in Netflix manual.

It is better to keep original order if you compare two videos only as otherwise people might be confused.

However, I do have opposite order in my FFmpeg GUI ([FFMetrics](https://github.com/fifonik/FFMetrics)).
The reason is -- it is possible to specify a multiple distorted files to the program so it is easier to understand and use:
ffmetrics.exe [options] ref distorted1 [distorted2] [distorted3] [distorted4] ...

Your command line is also correct:
ffmpeg -i reference -i distorted [0]...[refdeint];[refdeint]...[ref];[1](https://github.com/fifonik/FFMetrics)...[b];[b]...[c];[c][ref]libvmaf...

After all re-mapping streams supplied to libvmaf in correct order: distorted then reference.
You must not swap two "-i file" options there as this will change your logic dramatically.

P.S. This was simplified version of what is actually happening :)

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I realised that yesterday and forgot to close it here. Anyways, your answer is a lot more verbose. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

The FFmpeg filter expects the first input to be the encoded video stream and the 2nd input to be the reference stream.

It may be (I haven't checked) that the VMAF computation is symmetric with relation to inputs, so in effect, the order may not matter.

Comment: that's the thing. In the official documentation, it says first param is to be a referenced stream and the second param to be the encoded one.

Comment: The official docs for the ffmpeg filter is at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf. I've added a note about input order, which will appear tonight.